# Dota 2 Green Line for Obs and skill or Yellow Line for spawn box not showing

Tags: dota-2

Is there anyway to revert the settings? Idk what I do that I never have those Line showing. But as I saw others play or screenshot they have one. Like this one for obs: [image: obs]

Or this one for spawn box:

[image: spawn box]

I only had those faint light but not the hard line. Anyone can help?

Note: I had turn on the Alt option which show spawn boxes yet still no avail

Thanks

Comment: What's your OS? I'm pretty sure, if you had turn on the Alt option, it really must work or you should report to Valve. I'm playing all this patch and I have never heard about this problem from anyone

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. I also don't saw the tower radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year I've been trying to solve out why it was happening. It was the video graphic driver problem. I reinstall my NVIDIA driver and the hard line was showing up at long last, thanks to everyone who help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Options
and you have under interface you have these options
[image]

Comment: yes i turn them on already, not working for me